# How can I sum value in 8 textboxes to the a single textbox?

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I can't find a way to do this. I think it's a very basic question, but i'm just new with excel VBA and can't find the right formula.

Recently i understand that to do the sum, i have to change each of the **`textboxes`** into integer first, then i can add it to a single **`textbox`**, so i'm converting each value into integer while i sum them one by one to a text box.

I have tried this code.

```
Private Sub txtTotal_Change() 
txtTotal.Value = CInt(txtKas) + CInt(txtInvestasi) + CInt(txtDanaTerbatas) + CInt(txtBruto) + ...
End Sub
```

How can i sum this multiple textboxes (8 textboxes) into a single textbox?

Comment: Textbox, i cant post picture to explain my question.
after i hold all the number and sum the value in the last Textbox, i then print it to cell at excel. 
The problem is i cant do the sum in the textbox.

Comment: Why is it `txtTotal_Change()`? Shouldn't you call something like `txtTotal_Sum()` to sum all those textboxes and put result into txtTotal when any of them are changed? The txtTotal should be unchangeable by user (Lock it). And I think you should use `CInt(textbox.Value)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

I have change into this code


`Private Sub txtTotal_Sum()
   txtTotal = CInt(txtKas.Value) + CInt(Investasi.Value) + CInt(DanaTerbatas.Value)
End Sub`

And i also locked the last textbox, But the result did not came up.

Comment: You need to call this `txtTotal_Sum()` on `TextboxName_Change()` of all other textboxes. What you want is auto update when any of those textboxes are changed right?

Comment: Yes, that's the word, i want an autoupdate, Let me try first

Comment: @PatricK Sorry, i still can't do the autoupdate, could you help me with the code please?

I'm trying this

`Private Sub txtTotal_Change()
txtTotal_Sum() = CInt(txtKas.Value) + CInt(Investasi.Value) + CInt(DanaTerbatas.Value)
 
End Sub`

Detailed explanation will do, because i am totaly new with excel VB.Thank you very much @PatricK

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for reviewing John,i'll keep that in mind for the next questions i asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add **Change** Events on your text boxes that are user changeable.

Lets say I have below UserForm and **TextBox1** to **TextBox3**:
[image: UserForm1]
TextBox3 will be the Sum of TextBox1 and TextBox2.

Right click **UserForm1** under Project and select **View Code**, then put in the **TextBoxesSum** Sub (I use Double type for accepting decimals):

```
Private Sub TextBoxesSum()
    Dim Total As Double
    Total = 0
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) > 0 Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox1.Value)
    If Len(TextBox2.Value) > 0 Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox2.Value)
    ' Add more for the rest of your text boxes
    TextBox3.Value = Total
End Sub
```

To be safe and smart, you should also put in key checking from user input. Due to the amount of text boxes you have it is better to have a Function to handle it:

```
Private Function NumericOnly(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger) As MSForms.ReturnInteger
    Dim Key As MSForms.ReturnInteger
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 46, 48 To 57 ' Accept only decimal "." and numbers [0-9]
            Set Key = KeyAscii
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0 ' Minor bug earlier
            Set Key = KeyAscii
    End Select
    Set NumericOnly = Key
End Function
```

Now back to the UserForm1 object, right click TextBox1 and **View Code**, put in:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    TextBoxesSum
End Sub
```

Also do checking on the KeyPress event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    KeyAscii = NumericOnly(KeyAscii)
End Sub
```

Now copy above 2 set of TextBox Sub and paste below, then replace the string before underscore to match the name of the text boxes you have.

Sample output:
[image: Sample]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PatricK finally i got the answer for this problem. I really appreciate your help

Comment: How if the user make mistake? are there the built in function for Undo button in excel VBA?

Comment: Undo on user made mistake? AFAIK, there isn't a built in feature to Undo. You will have to implement it from scratch. It will be complicated code, are you up for that? You should instruct users to be careful/mindful when entering data (we have stopped them putting anything other than numbers and decimal - but not multiple decimals).

Comment: Maybe i should study more about VB, i thought that there's an Undo button for this. Thank you for your advise Patrick.

Answer (score 1):

You (probably) do not want to sum the values from your textboxes when someone tries to change the value in the totals box - you want to sum them when a value in any of the other eight boxes change.

The simplest way to do this is probably to create a simple macro to sum the values of the textboxes, and then call that from the change-events of the 8 which the user may change.

**The macro to sum the textboxes and put them into the totals box**

```
Private Sub sum_boxes()
    txtTotal = CLng(txtKas.Value) + CLng(Investasi.Value) + CLng(DanaTerbatas.Value)
End Sub
```

**What a change event will look like**

```
Private Sub txtKas_Change() 
    Call sum_boxes
End Sub
```

You need to make one change-event for each of the eight boxes, as mentioned previously.

On a completely different note, using a textbox to store the total may be a bad idea, as you don't want your users to change what's in it. One option is to lock the textbox, as PatricK suggests, another is to use a different object to hold the number, e.g. a label, and just change its caption to be similar to whatever your total is at the moment.

Comment: Thank you @eirikdaude 
I have followed your code, but it's says object require for this code

`txtTotal = CLng(txtKas.Value) + CLng(Investasi.Value) + CLng(DanaTerbatas.Value) `