# Run-time error 1004 WorksheetFunction.Sum

Tags: vba, powerpoint

When using the below within powerpoint, I constantly get

> ```
> Run-time error 1004 - Unable to get the Sum property of the WorksheetFunction class
> ```

Can anyone help?

```
TextBox10.Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Staff_Engagement_1.Value, Annual_Cost_To_Business_1.Value, Cost_To_Absence_1.Value, (-1) * TextBox11.Value)
```

Comment: Is there non numeric values in your sheets?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `worksheetfunction` in PowerPoint.  Since i'm assuming you're using a form by the `TextBox10.Value`, see [How can I sum value in 8 textboxes to the a single textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796684/how-can-i-sum-value-in-8-textboxes-to-the-a-single-textbox)